# how to made a middleware which can work as function if callback is provided?

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, middleware

I want to make a middleware just like passport.authenticate which can work as a middleware
e.g

```
req.get('/home', middleware,(req, res)=>{
      //some code
})
```

and it can also work as a function if a callback is provided like

```
req.get('/home',(req,res)=>{
   auth.checkAuth((err,user)=>{
     //some code  
  })
     //some code
})
```

.................................................................................................
auth.js file
this is what I am doing-

```
exports.checkAuth=async(req,res,next,callback)=>{
    console.log(callback)
    const token=req.header('Authorization').replace('Bearer ',"");
    try{
        const decodedPayload= await jwt.verify(token,secretKey);
        const user=await User.findOne({_id:decodedPayload._id,'tokens.token':token});
        if(!user){
            throw Error("please! authenticate.")
        }
        req.user=user;
        req.token=token;
        res.locals.users=user;
        if(typeof(callback)=='function'?true:false){
          return  callback(null,user);
        }
        next();
    }
   catch(e){
        if(typeof(callback)=='function'?true:false){
          return  callback(e,null);
        }
        res.status(401).send(e);
    }
}
```

but I am unable to add callback functionality.

Comment: `auth.checkAuth((err,user)=>{...});` can't work because you never pass `req` or `res` or `next` to it.  Middleware is a very specific type of function with a precise calling convention.  That exact function can only be used elsewhere if you call it with exactly the same context and arguments as a middleware would normally be called.

Comment: Yes, it could be useful for you to look at some tutorials on the subject like you can find a few here: https://tutorama.info/CTG/MiddleWare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Middlewares have access to the req,res,next and this is done by express and they are just special kind of function in which req,res,next are provided by express. so if we want a function that can work as a middleware and can also work as a function in which we can pass a optional callback we have to do set the default value of callback to null :-

```
exports.checkAuth=async(req,res,next,callback=null)=>{
console.log(callback)
const token=req.header('Authorization').replace('Bearer ',"");
try{
    const decodedPayload= await jwt.verify(token,secretKey);
    const user=await User.findOne({_id:decodedPayload._id,'tokens.token':token});
    if(!user){
        throw Error("please! authenticate.")
    }
    req.user=user;
    req.token=token;
    res.locals.users=user;
    if(typeof(callback)=='function'?true:false){
      return  callback(null,user);
    }
    next();
}
 catch(e){
    if(typeof(callback)=='function'?true:false){
      return  callback(e,null);
    }
    res.status(401).send(e);
 }
}
```

now to use it  as middleware:-

```
req.get('/home',checkAuth,(req, res)=>{
  //some code
})
```

to use it as a function with optional callback:-

```
req.get('/home',(req,res)=>{
    auth.checkAuth((err,user)=>{
       res.send(err);  
    })
      res.send(user);
  })
```